# Como fazer um loop no código python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Preciso fazer com que os comentários `(["COMENTARIO1","COMENTARIO2","COMENTARIO3"])` se repitam N vezes num preenchimento randômico, da forma que fiz, por mais que no range tenha colocado 30, eles são impressos 3 vezes somente.

```
def comente_foto(self):
    for k in range(30):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/B_0ggQsjMJ-/")
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 90)")
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
        comentarios = ["COMENTARIO1","COMENTARIO2","COMENTARIO3"]
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh').click()
        campo_comentario = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh').clear()
        campo_comentario = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh').send_keys(comentarios[k])
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,2))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Publicar')]").click()
        time.sleep(random.randint(5,6))
```

Answer (score -1):

Você criou uma lista chamada "comentarios" com **três elementos:**

```
comentarios = ["COMENTARIO1","COMENTARIO2","COMENTARIO3"]
```

No seu laço **for** o k varia de **0 até 29**, então na linha abaixo:

```
campo_comentario = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh').send_keys(comentarios[k])
```

Quando k=0  => Escreve "COMENTARIO1"

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh').send_keys(comentarios[0])
```

Quando k=1 => Escreve "COMENTARIO2"

```
campo_comentario = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh').send_keys(comentarios[1])
```

Quando k=2 => Escreve "COMENTARIO3"

```
 campo_comentario = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh').send_keys(comentarios[2]) # Escreve COMENTARIO3
```

Quando k=3 até 29: => não escreve nada

```
campo_comentario = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh').send_keys(comentarios[3])
```

Não existe o elemento comentario[3] ate comentario[29] na sua lista, o Python deveria dar erro de **"list index out of range"** mas provavelmente o Selenium simplesmente ignora não escreve nada.

Para corrigir o código insira mais um laço FOR, segue código:

```
def comente_foto(self):
    for k in range(30):
        for j range(3): 
            driver = self.driver
            driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/B_0ggQsjMJ-/")
            time.sleep(3)
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 90)")
            time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
            comentarios = ["COMENTARIO1","COMENTARIO2","COMENTARIO3"]
            driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh').click()
            campo_comentario = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh').clear()
            campo_comentario = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh').send_keys(comentarios[j])
            time.sleep(random.randint(1,2))
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Publicar')]").click()
            time.sleep(random.randint(5,6))
```